# Javascript window.print() not recognizing window object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to provide a button to open a browser level print dialog on a window. I first tried window.print(); with an inline "onclick" on an `<input>` and then a click() function on the input using jQuery, and both give the same error when clicked:

> TypeError: Property 'print' of object [object global] is not a function

I should point out that this is a popup window, but I wouldn't have thought that would matter except that any form of using window.print() on the parent page works fine.

Seemed like something must be happening to the window object somewhere, so I did the following in console:

**window.name**

"JOIN"

**window.self**

Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}

**window.location**

Location {assign: function, replace: function, reload: function, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "http://local.xxx.xxx:8080"…}

So it SEEMS like the window object is there and defined as expected.

I can even run other methods like close(), confirm(), alert(), scrollTo(), etc on this same window object and they work fine. So why wouldn't print()?

The contents of the page don't seem to matter, and I will also say we are not using iFrames or frames. I did replace ALL the content of the popup with just

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>Foo</body>
</html>
```

with the same results. So I'm fairly certain none of our other code is interfering.

**EDIT**

The code that I was using to trigger print():

```
$('.foobar').click(function(){
    window.print();
});
```

tho now I'm just doing it in console.

The button

```
<input type="button" class="foobar" value="Print" />
```

Comment: It'd help a whole lot if you'd post the code by which you set up the click handler for the button.

Answer (score 9):

This would happen if you have an element with an id of `print`.

Element IDs become properties of the `window` (the global object), hiding any existing members with the same name

Comment: Ouch. BTW isn't this behaviour deprecated by any chance?

Comment: @Kos perhaps but Chrome and Safari do it too. Firefox doesn't.

Comment: @Kos: Actually, AFAIK, it was recently standardized.

Comment: We all wish this behavior was deprecated.

Comment: Dang, I thought for sure this would be it, but just did a search and no elements with an ID of "print". A bunch that have "print" IN the ID name--like "print-close", etc--but none of JUST "print".

Answer (score 3):

I think that SLaks is on to something.  In case it is not a DOM element, you might try sticking in a setter function to trap any errant javascript that might be defining a global variable.  Stick something like this at the top of your page before any other javascript:

```
window.__defineSetter__(
    "print",
    function(){alert("GOTCHA!"); debugger;}
);
```

Open the page with your javascript debugger active and it should halt on anything that changes window.print to something else.  Go up the call stack to find the guilty party.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. Not in the exact way that @SLaks suggested, but it put us on the right track:

Ran

```
window.__defineSetter__("print", function(){alert("GOTCHA!"); debugger;});
```

early on, and discovered that a script far upstream was defining print:

```
var print = blah blah
```

So we aliased the print() method:

```
window.realPrint = window.print;
```

and used that. It's hacky, but it will work temporarily until we can address the upstream issue more thoroughly. Anyway, thought this debugging method and little hack might be useful to someone else.

Comment: I should mention that my solution above was suggested privately by @Brendan Robert. Credit to him!